Decoding Source-ToTarget-TransparentContainer using pycrate
I am trying to decode Source-ToTarget-TransparentContainer using pycrate. Below is the code -
from pycrate_asn1dir import S1AP

from pycrate_asn1dir import RRCLTE

from pycrate_asn1rt.utils import * 

S1_HANDOVER_REQUEST = S1AP.S1AP_PDU_Descriptions.S1AP_PDU
        
S1_HANDOVER_REQUEST.from_aper(unhexlify(b'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'))


Src_Tgt_container = get_val_at(S1_HANDOVER_REQUEST, ['initiatingMessage','value','HandoverRequest','protocolIEs'])[5]['value'][1]

mymsg = RRCLTE.EUTRA_InterNodeDefinitions.HandoverPreparationInformation
mymsg.from_uper(Src_Tgt_container)

But I am not getting any value. Appreciate if someone can help.
